# array_unique not removing duplicate values php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, duplicates

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I have tried searching but cannot seem to find an answer. I may just have the piece of code in the wrong place.

I have counted the duplicate values input from various select boxes, which were sent over via $_GET. Using these duplicates, if more than (whatever the set amount is) then it will run through a mysql query. This is all working fine.

The issue is that I need to remove duplicates that are returned from the mysql query. Here is my code:

```
if ($countGearSelected >= 2) {      
        $gearSets = array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($_GET['gearPiece']), function($v) {
            return $v > 1;
        }));

        foreach ($gearSets as $gearSetKey => $gearSetValue) {

            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT twoPieceBonus FROM sets WHERE setName='".$gearSetValue."';");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                $twoPieceBonus .= urldecode($row['twoPieceBonus']).'</br></br>';

            }
            $twoPieceBonus = implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', $twoPieceBonus)));
            $twoSelected = substr($twoPieceBonus, 0, -10);

        }


    }else{
        $twoSelected = '';
    }
```

As you can see, I have tried the array_unique option on various other posts on SE but it doesn't appear to be working. I think I may be using it incorrectly?

Using DISTINCT doesn't work in the mysql query, as a few of the "sets" that are being queried have the same result (if that makes sense?).

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us the format of values in `$result`?

Comment: can you please print your $result value.

Comment: mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )

Comment: *"it doesn't appear to be working"*: that is quite vague. Of course `array_unique` works, so please provide a concrete data example, what you get from it, and how that differs from the desired result.

Comment: Replace <BR> tag with comma (,) or explode with <br>.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness, it is a little difficult to explain any better than I have in the original post. My best example would be, if you run a mysql query in the foreach loop, which loops through twice for 2 different "sets", and each one has an identical output (even though the query was different), how would I remove one of the duplicate output values

Comment: @stalinrajindian thanks dude! If you want to put that as an answer, I will mark it as correct as that works perfectly (although I did need to implode with the </br> tags too)

Comment: Be aware that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you should use prepared statements. Also, executing a query in a loop is not efficient. You should perform one query only with the `in` operator.

Comment: @trincot How would that be done with my existing code, any ideas?

Comment: I added an answer about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php): use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to avoid this.

Secondly, it is often a bad idea to execute a query in each iteration of a loop. And in this case it can be avoided. Instead of an equality comparison in your `where` clause, you could use the `in` operator and compare to all gear sets in one go.

This will also solve the matter of getting distinct values. With only one query executing, you *can* use `distinct` now.

Here is how the code would look like. I could not test this, but I expect mistakes (if any) can be easily fixed:

```
$twoSelected = '';
if ($countGearSelected >= 2) {      
    $gearSets = array_keys(array_filter(
        array_count_values($_GET['gearPiece']), function($v) {
            return $v > 1;
        }
    ));

    // Create comma separated list of question marks
    $placeHolders = implode(",", array_fill(0, count($gearSets), "?"));
    // Prepare SQL statement with it
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 
            "SELECT DISTINCT twoPieceBonus 
             FROM sets 
             WHERE setName IN ($placeHolders);");

    // All gearSet values are strings:
    $types = str_repeat("s", count($gearSets));
    // Turn the gearSets into references
    $gearSetRefs = [];
    foreach ($gearSets as $i => $_) {
         $gearSetRefs[] = &$gearSets[$i];
    }
    // Bind arguments
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $types, ...$gearSetRefs); // the splat operator
    // Now we are all set to (safely) execute the query 
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    // Let the result of the URL decoding still be an array
    $twoPieceBonus = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $twoPieceBonus[] = urldecode($row['twoPieceBonus']);
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close ($stmt);
    // ... and then use implode to insert those HTML breaks
    $twoSelected = implode("</br></br>", $twoPieceBonus);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, it appears to work right off the bat! The only issue (and probably one for another question as it could probably get quite lengthy) is that, out of my 6 selections (for the gearsets), if you pick 2 of one gearset, and 4 of another, it outputs the fourPieceBonus for both (this query is iterated again for 3 and 4 piece bonuses)

Comment: If you have this code inside another loop, you would need to store the results not in a simple variable (like `$twoSelected`), but add them to an array, so that after the outer loop has finished, you still have access to the individual results. But yes, probably I am oversimplifying what you are trying to tell me, so maybe ask a new question providing all the details.

Comment: Will do. Thanks so much for your help. I'll post another question now. Very much appreciated :)

Comment: Quick question regarding your answer, sorry to keep bothering you... Do I need to free the result after each iteration or close it? It doesn't seem to want to work with the other iterations of the code after this one has run and I believe this could be the reason

Comment: Yes, use `mysqli_stmt_close ($stmt)`

Comment: Also reset any array variables, like do `$gearSetRefs = []` before the loop. I'll add it in the answer's code.